# Easy UI file Uploader

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with easy ui and making a a file uploader which is connect with mysql and php

here is my code for inserting new data

```
<?php

$desc = $_REQUEST['resultDesc'];

//------------------ Check file for error message ----------------
if($_FILES["resultFile"]["error"] <= 0)
{   
//------------------ Check wether file exists -----------------
if (!(file_exists("results/" . $_FILES["resultFile"]["name"])))
{
   //----------- Upload File ----------------------------------
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resultFile"]["tmp_name"],
  "results/" . $_FILES["resultFile"]["name"]);

  include 'Connection.php';

//--------------- Todays Date ----------------------------
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$file = $_FILES["resultFile"]["name"];

$sql = "insert into results(id,date,description,filename)  
values(NULL,'$today','$desc','$file')";

$result = @mysql_query($sql);

if ($result)
{
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
} 
else 
{
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
}

//--------------------- Close COnnection ------------------
mysql_close($connection);

}   
}

else
echo json_encode(array('msg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
?>
```

while on user side i have this code

```
<div class="fitem">
<label>Description</label>
 <textarea name="resultDesc" style="width:300px;height:100px;resize:none" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true"></textarea>
 <label>Result File</label>
 <input type="file" name="resultFile" size = "30px;" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
 </div>
```

The above code is not working. Kindly please help. File Uploading is not included in easy ui , i am making  a custom one.

Comment: Define what "not working" means exactly.

Comment: what error mysql_query returns? it seems that query is failing due to some reason

Comment: The file uploading is not working. The save buttons hangs

Comment: I am unable to trace the error myself, File uploading is on top but its not working as well

Comment: I think the question is well explained. I didnt hope the users to close this question. Also enough details to help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace

```
$sql = "insert into results(id,date,description,filename)  
values(NULL,'$today','$desc','$file')";
```

with this:

```
$sql = "insert into `results`(`id`,`date`,`description`,`filename`)  
values(NULL,'$today','$desc','$file')";
```

Use backquotes to escape field names.

Comment: File is not uploading as well on desired folder

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES["resultFile"]["error"])` shows anything?

Comment: no it didnt, there is a java script which is calling this php file

Answer (score 0):

If at all a javascript is calling this php file, try.
    { window.location = "your file name"; }.

Try echoing all your variable as 
    { $_REQUEST['resultDesc'], $_FILES["resultFile"]["name"] }